# Testing for C object setters/getters

Tags: python, c

I'm writing a Python object in C with a set of setters and getters. I want to limit the type of the variable accessed through the setters/getters, and raise a TypeError if the incorrect type is passed. For instance, `class_instance.minute = "string"` should raise a TypeError as minute expects an integer:

```
int
Event_set_min(EventObject *self, PyObject *val, void *closure)
{
        VERIFY_NUMBER(val);
        self->e->time->tm_min = (int) PyLong_AsLong(val);
        return 0;
}
```

and the `VERIFY_NUMBER` macro expands to:

```
#define VERIFY_NUMBER(val) \
if (val == NULL) {                                                        \
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "Cannot set to NULL");           \
        return -1;                                                        \
} else if (!val->ob_type->tp_as_number) {                                 \
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "Cannot set to non-number type); \
        return -1;                                                        \
}
```

If I instantiate the object and run `instance.minute = "string"` (or None, etc) I get a TypeError as expected. I'm using the following code to test:

```
with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
        a.minute = "string"
```

This gives me an AttributeError and the following trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lincoln/Documents/disorg/./test.py", line 38, in test_minute
    a.minute = "abc"
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/unittest/case.py", line 226, in __exit__
    self._raiseFailure("{} not raised".format(exc_name))
AttributeError: '_AssertRaisesContext' object has no attribute '_raiseFailure'
```

What am I doing incorrectly? Thanks!

Comment: Tip: Instead of macros, just write functions and let the optimizer figure it out.

Comment: Your C is broken. There's broken stuff in the parts we can see - your validation logic is wrong, which can lead to inconsistency between the return value and the error state - but we don't have enough information to determine whether that's actually the (entire) cause of the symptoms you're observing. For all we know, there may be more broken stuff. We'd need a [mcve] to be sure.

Comment: Your `VERIFY_NUMBER` isn't a correct check for a number, and "a number" isn't what you need to check for anyway - you need something that `PyLong_AsLong` accepts, and the easiest way to check that is to call `PyLong_AsLong` and see whether it raised an error (with [`PyErr_Occurred`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html#c.PyErr_Occurred)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your macro `VERIFY_NUMBER` isn't correct. You should use [`PyLong_Check`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html), which:

> Return true if its argument is a PyLongObject or a subtype of
> PyLongObject. This function always succeeds.

I would rewrite your macro and turn it into a new function like this:

```
static int Verify_Number(PyObject *value)
{
    int rc = 1;

    if (!PyLong_Check(value)) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "should be int");
        rc = 0;
    }

    return rc;
}
```

Then call this from your function `Event_set_min`:

```
int Event_set_min(EventObject *self, PyObject *val, void *closure)
{
    int rc = -1;

    if (!Verify_Number(val)) {
        return rc;
    }

    Py_INCREF(val);
    Py_XDECREF(self->e->time->tm_min);
    self->e->time->tm_min = val;

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I've added the `Py_INCREF` and `Py_XDECREF` calls to increment/decrement the reference counts of objects - which will avoid having memory leaks.

---

### Edit:

As pointed out in the comments, it may be better to use `PyLong_AsLong` and check whether an error is raised with `PyErr_Occurred` in order to respect the `__index__` protocol.

So here's an alternative solution:

```
#include <Python.h>

/*
 * class Event:
 *     def __new__(cls, *a, **kw):
 *         event_obj = object.__new__(cls)
 *         event_obj._minute = 0
 *         return event_obj
 *
 *     def __init__(self, minute=None):
 *         if event and isinstance(event, 'int'):
 *             self._minute = minute
 *
 *     @property
 *     def minute(self):
 *         return self._minute
 *
 *     @minute.setter
 *     def minute(self, value):
 *         if not value or not isinstance(value, int):
 *             raise TypeError("value should be int")
 *         self._minute = value
 */


typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    int minute;
} EventObject;

static void
Event_dealloc(EventObject *self)
{
    Py_TYPE(self)->tp_free((PyObject *) self);
}

static PyObject *
Event_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kw)
{
    int rc = -1;
    EventObject *self = NULL;
    self = (EventObject *) type->tp_alloc(type, 0);

    if (self) {
        self->minute = 0;
        rc = 0;
    }

    if (rc < 0) {
        Py_XDECREF(self);
    }
    return (PyObject *) self;
}

static int
Event_init(EventObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kw)
{
    int rc = -1;
    static char *keywords[] = {"minute", NULL};

    if (PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kw,
                                    "|O", keywords,
                                    &self->minute))
    {
        rc = 0;
    }

    return rc;
}

static PyObject *
Event_getminute(EventObject *self, void *closure)
{
    return PyLong_FromLong(self->minute);
}

static int Verify_Number(PyObject *value, int *real_val)
{
    int rc = 1;

    int minute = PyLong_AsLong(value);

    if (minute == -1 && PyErr_Occurred()) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "value should be int");
        rc = 0;
    }
    else {
        *real_val = minute;
    }

    return rc;
}

static int
Event_setminute(EventObject *self, PyObject *value, void *closure)
{
    int rc = -1;
    int minute = 0;

    if (!Verify_Number(value, &minute)) {
        return rc;
    }

    self->minute = minute;
    return 0;
}

static PyGetSetDef Event_getsetters[] = {
    {"minute", (getter)Event_getminute, (setter)Event_setminute}
};

static PyTypeObject EventType = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)
    .tp_name = "foo.Event",
    .tp_doc = "Event objects",
    .tp_basicsize = sizeof(EventObject),
    .tp_itemsize = 0,
    .tp_flags = Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE,
    .tp_new = Event_new,
    .tp_init = (initproc) Event_init,
    .tp_dealloc = (destructor) Event_dealloc,
    .tp_getset = Event_getsetters,
};

static PyModuleDef module = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT, "foo", NULL, -1, NULL
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_foo(void)
{
    PyObject *m = NULL;
    if (PyType_Ready(&EventType) < 0)
        return NULL;
    if ((m = PyModule_Create(&module)) == NULL)
        return NULL;
    Py_XINCREF(&EventType);
    PyModule_AddObject(m, "Event", (PyObject *) &EventType);
    return m;
}
```

Comment: `PyLong_Check` is too specific. There's an [`__index__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__index__) protocol for objects like NumPy integers to be treated as ints, and `PyLong_AsLong` respects that protocol, but `PyLong_Check` doesn't.